# jQuery not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have a PHP verification like this:

```
if (empty($_POST['name'])) {


        $userMessage = '<script type="text/javascript"> 


        Nname() ;


        </script>';
        }
```

Function above corresponds with jQuery:

```
   function Nname () {

        $('#Nname').slideToggle(500).delay(3000).slideToggle(500);

    }
```

Which reveals a div containing the notification:

```
<div class="warning" id="Nname">

    <div id="warn_name"> Please enter your first name. </div>

</div>
```

I have a series of notifications set up like this and everything works great in Chrome, Opera and Safari. However, Firefox and IE show nothing at all.

Upon clicking the button which triggers the notifications, in Firefox and IE page simply reloads and shows nothing.

How can I fix this?

### SOLVED!:

I posted the solution below!

Comment: Do you have Firebug installed? Any errors being thrown? (Ctrl-Shift-J for Firefox will bring up the error console).

Comment: Firebug doesn't show anything. After clicking the button (which triggers above code) there's a "warning" note in the log:

"Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead."

Comment: Is your javascript code being emitted after the markup it is targeting? If so, you will need to defer execution until the web page has been downloaded.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - Renaming doesn't seem to do much, still nothing.
[at]Chris - I'm sorry, don't quite follow you. Can you explain what do you mean? My JS files are all loaded in the beginning of the file (before any validation) if that's what you're referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem wasn't with either jQuery or PHP. What was causing the issues was the submit button. I have a rollover image as a submit button and it doesn't execute the PHP script upon clicking in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Rollover image was created using jQuery and some modifications solved the issue.

Detailed explanation:
[Submit rollover button not working in FF and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335015/submit-rollover-button-not-working-in-ff-and-ie)

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP try this, I am thinking the function isn't getting called.

```
if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
  $userMessage = 
  '<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log(\'here\');
        Nname() ;
   });
  </script>';
}
```

*or try this, without document ready* (just see if it sends a console log);

```
if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
      $userMessage = 
      '<script type="text/javascript"> 
            console.log(\'here\');
            Nname() ;
      </script>';
    }
```

Comment: Okay, try doing it without document.ready, and just do console.log() or an alert to see if that part is actually working.

Comment: Yep, good point. Sorry I missed that. That is probably why fjanecic got the 500 error.

Comment: Escaping ' doesn't display server error, but it is still not working (problem is the same). :/

Comment: Do you get a console message that says 'here'? If not then this function is not getting called properly from your PHP.

Comment: Nope, doesn't display "here" in the log. I copied your code from above: $userMessage = '<script type="text/javascript"> console.log(\'here\');
            Nname() ;
  
   
  </script>';

Comment: To clarify: "here" appears in log for e.g. Chrome (where everything works fine) but doesn't in Firefox.