# Submit rollover button not working in FF and IE

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a rollover submit button in HTML:

```
<input type="image" id="join" name="join" src="images/join.png" value="join">
```

And I use JS code for the rollover/hover function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#join').hover(
                    function(){ 
                        $(this).attr({ src : 'images/rollover/joinOver.png'});
                    },
                    function(){ 
                        $(this).attr({ src : 'images/join.png'});                }
                );
            });
        </script>
```

It works fine in all browsers except for Firefox and IE. If I add a normal "submit" button (`input type = "submit"`) it works fine everywhere.

I tried putting `type="submit"` in HTML and then adding a hover image effect via CSS (both in HTML and with using a `class` in a seperate stylesheet) but it doesn't work.

How can I have a rollover button which works accross "all" browsers? 
(Tested in Chrome, FF, IE, Opera, Safari)

### NOTE:

Just to clarify, I don't have problem with creating a rollover image, but creating a rollover image which works as "submit" button for a form (launching a PHP script).

My code **shows** rollover in all browsers, but it **doesn't function** as a "submit" button in FF and IE.

Comment: Just Google "rollover image IE 8" - am sure you'll find **"Oodles"** on Google

Comment: Plus if your button is a "submit" button, then it can't be `<input type="image"` it has to be `<input type="submit"` otherwise it'll just hang there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did, before posting. Most posts I've found have suggested implementing CSS directly in HTML or in a seperate file. Unfortunately, I tried that and it doesn't seems to work in any of the browsers I tested with. I posted my problem here to see if there is anything specifically wrong with my code which is causing it not to work.
EDIT: To answer your second comment, if I put type=submit it adds a standard button, not my image. Doesn't help me.

Comment: We used to do basic rollovers in the 90s with versions of IE that would make people cringe today LOL! I suggest you further your research with just a simple JS rollover method instead of jQuery, which may be the initial problem. I'm sure you will find something. Have a look at [this one for example](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?228379-Change-image-on-rollover) with a few example on there that I'm sure are bound to work. See also Example # 4 [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?800497-Rollover-not-working-in-IE) using CSS

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/JS/javascript_rollover.html - http://javascriptkit.com/script/script2/imagerollover.shtml - http://www.quackit.com/javascript/image_rollovers.cfm - and the list goes on... Find more, test them out and I guarantee you, that you will find something that works cross-browser.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't have problem with creating a rollover image, but creating a rollover image which works as "submit" button for an HTML form. Can you help me with that? As far as I saw, your links only show how to create generic rollover effect. My inital code shows rollover in all browsers, but it doesn't function as a "submit" button in FF and IE.

Comment: Ok, got it. [See example #5 here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?423461-Rollover-on-a-submit-form-button) just change the image sources for yours, see how that works out.

Comment: See this one also (jQuery) http://blog.mirthlab.com/2008/04/18/simple-image-submit-button-rollovers-with-jquery/ - After Googling "rollover submit button" for both

Comment: Here's another simple JS example http://www.idocs.com/tags/forms/index_famsupp_107.html

Comment: Have a look at what I posted as an [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19335501/1415724), tested in both IE8 and FF 24

Comment: So, how are you making out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out:

**http://jsfiddle.net/LcnrJ/3/**

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="join" value="SEND"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".join").hover(function(){
        $(".join").toggleClass("newphoto");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Tested in both IE 8 and FF 24

Change both `1.jpg` and `2.jpg` image sources respectively and `action=""`.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html><head>
 <title>Form Test</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- Hide from old browsers
 
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
 // unhide -->
</script>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onLoad="MM_preloadImages('1.jpg')">
 <form action="" method="POST">
 <input type="image" src="2.jpg" border="0" id="submitbutton" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('submitbutton','','1.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it's not working for me. I can't leave my action field empty because it corresponds with the PHP script (<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>), otherwise it doesn't work. I'll have a look at other links you posted, they should help me wrap this up! :)

Comment: @fjanecic You don't have to leave it blank. Just use `action="your_action_file.php"` or `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`

Comment: @fjanecic Which browser and version are you using? And what exactly is "not" working, can you elaborate? I'm really curious to know, because I tested this fully before submitting.

Comment: I tested with latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera. Upon clicking the button, nothing happens.It was like that previously only in FF and IE but now it's accross all browsers I tested with. Rest of my code might be interfering with it somehow.

Comment: @fjanecic Something is interferring for sure. If you use my code just the way it is, and replacing the `1.jpg` and `2.jpg` images and the action, without any other code, you'll see that it will work.

Comment: Tried once again, made sure not to change anything. Still no go. I appreciate the effort but it's not working for me.